# WiX: Database uninstall

Tags: database, iis, wix, uninstallation

I have completed a WiX 3.9 project, with one hiccup...

It is able to:
-- skip the EULA
-- ask the user for the database string
  -- save it in a RegKey
-- install files in the inetpub\wwwroot folder (defined by the client)
-- creates an AppPool
-- creates an IIS
-- creates a database
  -- runs a script to remove the database, if it already exists
  -- runs a script to create the entire database (tables and contents, necessary user)

However, during uninstall, everything is removed but the database does not drop.

I tested the script to drop the database by running it before the database is created.  It works.  I cannot get it to run at uninstall.

Here is my wix sql:SqlDatabase tag:

```
    <!-- - - - - DB/SQL Script - - - - -->
    <sql:SqlDatabase Id="CreateBingoServer" Server="[SERVERNAME]" Database="BingoServer" CreateOnInstall="yes" DropOnUninstall="yes" ContinueOnError="no" >

      <!-- Pre-Drop on Create -->
      <sql:SqlScript Id="PreDrop" BinaryKey="Drop" ExecuteOnInstall="yes" Sequence="1" ContinueOnError="yes" />
      <!-- Create on Install -->
      <sql:SqlScript Id="Script" BinaryKey="Database" ExecuteOnInstall="yes" Sequence="2" ContinueOnError="no" />
      <!-- Drop on Uninstall -->
      <sql:SqlScript Id="Drop" BinaryKey="Drop" ExecuteOnUninstall="yes" Sequence="1" ContinueOnError="no" />
      <!-- -->

    </sql:SqlDatabase>
```

For Drop, I have tried 'ExecuteOnUninstall' and 'RollbackOnUninstall'.

I have also tried:

```
      <sql:SqlScript Id="Drop" BinaryKey="Drop" ExecuteOnUninstall="yes" Sequence="1" ContinueOnError="no" SqlDb="CreateBingoServer" />
```

(outside the sql:SqlDatabase tag) and that does not run.  I have changed the 'Sequence' from 1 - 9; no change.

The verbose log shows the database is not found but SERVERNAME = "proper string from RegKey/installer input"

MSI (s) (8C:8C) [11:51:49:620]: APPCOMPAT: looking for appcompat database entry with ProductCode '{Some random GUID}'.

MSI (s) (8C:8C) [11:51:49:620]: APPCOMPAT: no matching ProductCode found in database.

...

MSI (s) (8C:8C) [11:51:49:888]: Component: Database; Installed: Local;   Request: Absent;   Action: Null

Any ideas?

Thank you, in advance.

Answer (score 2):

FWIW, I don't recommend running SQL scripts during uninstall.  Nothing worse then can't uninstall something because some SQL dependency is throwing an error.  Besides, it's user data.... just leave it.

I also don't like the IF EXIST DROP THEN CREATE pattern because you can lose user data.

Comment: The DROP before CREATE was, really, just to test the script to make sure it works.  In the final product I'm taking it out (I'm leaving it for now "just because", really).

Comment: I should add there are a couple exceptions.  One is  data that is static and the user has no expectation to change such as  code lookup tables.  Another is demo products where the requried functional requirement is the data should be reset every time the product is installed/repaired/upgraded.  IE not a production system.